# Integrate working JS code in TypeScript setup

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to fit this code on a TypeScript project, which is an adaptation of the `react-custom-scrollbars`.

Here is where I get lost with TypeScript, it needs type declaration for `style` and `props`, this is the one instance where I do not want TypeScript to do type checking since I know this code works, and I want to use it as a plugin.

Is there any way to deal with this type of situations?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-with-typescript-forked-ntsfq?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exclude` config in [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) like

`"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.my-file-to-exclude.ts", "**/*.my-js-file-to-exclude.js"]`

Comment: Thanks, will resort to that if I can not figure out how to defined the types as this is part of a file I actually want TypeScript to check, Do you know how I can defined the type for `style` and `props` in this example?